# JavaScript selectedIndex text on multiple choice

Tags: javascript, select

I have a list of tag in my input using Symfony Twig templating like that :

```
    <select id="choices-multiple-remove-button" class="form-control" name="choices-multiple-remove-button"  placeholder="Compétences" multiple>
    {% for skill in skills %}
      <option value="{{skill.id}}">{{skill.label}}</option>
      {% endfor %}
    </select>
  </div>
```

Here in JS i can get all values selected with "elements[i].value" :

```
function hello() {
  var elements = document.getElementById('choices-multiple-remove-button');
  for(var i=0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    console.log(elements[i].value);
    console.log(elements[i].options[elements[i].selectedIndex].text);
    // Throw Error //
  }
}
document.getElementById("workingbutton").addEventListener("click", hello);
```

Here :

```
console.log(elements[i].options[elements[i].selectedIndex].text);
```

Cannot read property 'undefined' of undefined at HTMLButtonElement.hello..
How can i do this please ? What's wrong ?

Comment: if multiple values are selected then what's your expected behavior???

Comment: to get their text content , with console.log(elements[i].value) print all the values, i want to print all the text content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter the selected options and then get its text content. In order to do that convert options property into an array, then use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method to filter selected options and finally use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to extract text values from selected options into an array.

```js
var element = document.getElementById('choices-multiple-remove-button');
console.log([...element.options].filter(ele => ele.selected).map(ele => ele.text));
```

```html
<select id="choices-multiple-remove-button" class="form-control" name="choices-multiple-remove-button" placeholder="Compétences" multiple>
  <option value="1" selected>1</option>
  <option value="2" selected>2</option>
</select>
```